# Change &amp; into & when show on json

Tags: javascript, php, json

So i have problem whit symbols "&", here my code on javascript

```
$("#shipCurr").change(function(){
        var curr = $(this).val();
        $("#shipPO").empty();
        if(curr != "")
        {
            $("#shipPO").prop('disabled',false);
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: host+"buypo/ListPOShippDoc",
                data:{
                    'curr':curr
                },
                cache: false,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log($("#shipPO").html(data));
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#shipPO").prop('disabled',true);
        }
        // console.log("test");
    });
```

and on php code

```
public function ListPOShippDoc()
    {
        $currency = $_POST['curr'];
        $fullName = $_SESSION['fullName'];

        $PONo = $this->shippDoc->ListPO($fullName,$currency)['items'];



        $option .= '<option value=""></option>';
        while ($val = $PONo->fetch_assoc()) {

            $option .= '<option value="'.utf8_decode($val['PONo']).'">'.utf8_decode($val['PONo']).'</option>';
        }

        echo $option;
    }
```

My problem is,if the PONo value like `H&M-000762-001` it show on my html into `H&amp;M-000762-001`.

How do i get wrong in here? Wy it show H`&amp;M-000762-001` not `H&M-000762-001`? Any idea?
I try `utf8_decode()` `utf8_encode()` is still same result `H&amp;M-000762-001`.

Comment: `why it show "H&M-000762-001" not "H&M-000762-001"` Sorry, I fail to see how these are different

Comment: @WillParky93 It's just that StackOverflow outputs `&amp;` as `&`, because its treated as the HTML entity. The question in raw format (if you click "edit" and look at that) had it right, and I've edited to display it properly.

Comment: How does the raw data, from the ajax success, looks like?

Comment: try to use `html_entity_decode`: `$option .= '<option value="'.utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($val['PONo'])).'">'.utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($val['PONo'])).'</option>';`

Comment: @Neodan : Well i try that but didnt show anything.

Comment: @Qirel : Thank you for edited.

Answer (score -3):

```
function convertSymbol($value)
{
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
    $ampersandval = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $value);
    return $ampersandval;
}
?>
```

/* mb_convert_encoding this function is used to Convert ISO to UTF-8 */
   Using str_replace function we can convert &amp to &

Comment: do you know the `html_entity_decode` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)?

Comment: 1) There's already `htmlspecialchars_decode()`/`html_entity_decode()`. 2) Code-only answers are bad for this community, always explain your answer with text!

Comment: "convert_encoding this function is used to Convert ISO to UTF-8" — Why are you doing that? The question doesn't mention it. Who uses 8859 in 2017 anyway?

Comment: The return of this function is always going to be null because `$convertedvalue` isn't even set

Comment: return $ampersandval; please change like this it will work

Comment: @Wolfzmus can you please check now

Comment: @Anitha S You didnt see my question......Why i need to Convert ISO to UTF-8 even I've allready use uft-8.